# When should I use file descriptors in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

i know what they are, but i dunno when i should use them. Are they useful? I think yes, but I want you to tell me in which situations a file descriptor could be useful. Thanks :D

Comment: This is a duplicate of a lot of other posts.  Please read them first- and post any **specific** questions you have. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting

Comment: You will also use them to read from both `stdin` and a file with a single loop, or to read from two different files within a loop (which itself is a bit duplicative as `stdin` is a file in and of itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most *obvious* case which springs to mind is:

```
myProgram >myProgram.output_and_error 2>&1
```

which sends both standard output and error to the same file.

I've also used:

```
myProgram 2>&1 | less
```

which will allow me to page through the output and error in sequence (rather than having error got to the terminal in "arbitrary" places in the output).

Basically, any time when you need to get at an already existing file descriptor, you'll find yourself using this.